# Soundcloud HTML5 Player: Events.FINISH only fired once

Tags: html, soundcloud

I'm using the SC HTML5 player, when one sound finishes, I load in another source, however the FINISH event only seems to fire for the first song, my code is as follows

```
//Set the source
document.getElementById("sc-widget").src = scPath;
//get the widget reference
var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
widget       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);
//set the finish event
widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, endSC);

function endSC() {
                    var scPath = "http://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F1848538&show_artwork=true&auto_play=true";
                    document.getElementById("sc-widget").src = scPath;
                    var widgetIframe = document.getElementById('sc-widget'),
                    widget       = SC.Widget(widgetIframe);
                    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, endSC);
}
```

I've tried setting the endSC target to another function but that doesn't work, what am I missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. SC.Widget method is working fine when I call it for the first time, but if I try to call it for the second time the console will fire "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentWindow' of null" error in http://w.soundcloud.com/player/api.js script. And that is where api.js script stops with actions (.Widget, .bind, etc.)

I found the solution. It's very weird, but it is a solution.
SoundCloud remote script is minified. Load it in your browser, C/P it in some online js beautifier and save it locally. Edit line 103 as follows:

```
return a.contentWindow;// || a.contentDocument.parentWindow
```

So I removed that .parentWindow call.

Save the file and call it in your page's head section. And that's it! Now FINISH event fires on every loaded widget.

I hope this will help.

Comment: End result of soundcloud api.js as of 10th October 2012: http://pastebin.com/S13JxRw3

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this question is over 10 years old, but it just came up for me now.

I recreated the iframe div from scratch. Otherwise, the SC.Widget.Events.FINISH will only fire when the original embed player finishes.

You must reset the DOM element events by completely recreating the iframe element, like so:

```
//EXAMPLE SC SONG IDs
let songIds = [216109050, 779324239, 130928732]
let incrementingIndex = 0

function playSongsInIframe() {
    let iframeParent = document.querySelector('#sound-player')
    let iframeElement = document.querySelector('#sound-player iframe')
    iframeElement.remove()

    //CODE TO ADD NEW SOUND IDs
    //yourSoundId = songIds[incrementingIndex]

    let newIframe = document.createElement('iframe')
    newIframe.id = "sound-" + yourSoundId
    newIframe.width = "100%"
    newIframe.height = "166"
    newIframe.scrolling="no" 
    newIframe.frameborder="no"
    newIframe.allow = "autoplay"
    newIframe.src = "https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/" + yourSoundId + "&amp;auto_play=true"
                    
    iframeParent.appendChild(newIframe)

    let widget = SC.Widget("sound-" + yourSoundId);

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, () => {
        console.log('Ready...');
        widget.play()
    });
    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.FINISH, () => {
        console.log('Song ended...');
        incrementingIndex++
        playSongsInIframe()
    });
}
```

One last consideration - this process must be started from a user event, like a click. You can add this function to the onclick attribute of an HTML button element:

```
<button onclick="playSongsInIframe()">Start Radio</button>
```